# How can I remove my navbar's hover animation on mobile devices?

Tags: html, css

My website's navbar has hover animations, and I want to remove these animations for mobile devices. However, I'm not sure how to "cancel" or prevent them from happening. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can I ask first to make it clear? So u want all the link in your navbar have no hover animation right? like bottom border?

Comment: @ProLuck Yep! I want all the navbar links to not be animated.

Comment: Okay, I will give some explain about how to solve your problem, first you must set adjustment to your screen (mobile), then you make your transition into `none` and change your width in hover pseudo-class into 0

Comment: You need to Include the code in the question itself

Answer (score 1):

You can use a media query to detect the screen width of the user who is viewing your website. Then on certain width, you can remove transition.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 550px) {
   li a:hover:after{
      transition: none !important; /* To Remove Just Transition */
      width: 0; /* To Remove The Underline (Psuedo Element) */
    }
}
```

If you have animations as well as transitions you can try setting the `animation-name:none;` which should disable all animations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries and set phone breakpoints if do that now you can edit the class that you set it for animation and remove it

If you want do it with JavaScript you can set Condition. That if the window min 480 remove animation